# Inconsistency in help center regarding [tag]s in title

Tags: feature-request, help-center

In the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page its written, that a good title contains "in [tag]". With that example:

> **Bad**: [php] session doubt
>
> **Good**: How can I redirect users to different pages based on session data in PHP?

But in the [tagging](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) page its said to *avoid* adding tags to the title

> Avoid inserting tags into titles in any of the following formats:
>
> - [question title] in [tag]

As pointed out by the tagging page and [this MSE question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles) tags shouldn't be inside the title and because of that, the "in PHP" should be removed from the "how to ask" help center page.

Comment: @Moritz Which is exactly what op is saying. There's an incoherence between the how to ask and the tagging page.

Comment: @Moritz "do something - [php]" is not but "do something in php" is, its very similar IMO, the tag alone states that it should be done in PHP, also one tag gets automatically added to the question html title. Because of that the browser title will be something like this "php - do something in php".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't contradictory (I believe), but it could be written better.

It looks to me like part of the confusion here is that the square brackets in the tagging page guidance are used both as variable demarcations (around "question title") *and* literals (around "tag"). Note the end of the sentence: "in any of the following **formats** *[emphasis mine]*".

In other words, it should say something more like

> Avoid inserting tags into titles in any of the following formats:
>
> - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet in [tag]

---

Putting a language name -- or other information -- that happens to also be present in the tags can sometimes be important to distinguish a question title.

The rule is not, and has never been, that anything present in the tags **must not** be in the title. It's that you don't need to force them into the title. "Why does AnnoyingLibrary fail to foo my bar?" is *much* better than "Failure to foo the bar", even though the question is also tagged [annoying-library].